# $.getJSON: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

On changing an item in a dropdown list, I'm supposed to make an AJAX call via jQuery. (I am using the new function **getJSON**, which automatically sets the Data Type to 'JSON', so I don't have to specify that.)

My code:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#mydropdown').change (function() {
        var lookupPath = "/" + $(location).attr('pathname').split('/')[1] + "/lookup";
        var jsonData = '{\"lookupIdentifier\":\"MY_LOOKUP\",\"secondParam\":\"PARAM\"}';
        alert('JSON Data is: ' + jsonData);

        var jqxhr = $.getJSON(lookupPath, jsonData).done(function(data) {
            alert('AJAX Call Completed. Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));    
        }).fail(function(d, textStatus, error) {
            alert('Failed: ' + d + " textStatus: " + textStatus + " error: " + error);
        });
```

First of all I verify the JSON string being passed in is correct, no syntax issues:

```
{"lookupIdentifier":"MY_LOOKUP","secondParam":"PARAM"}
```

It goes into fail(), Error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON from? Could it be that you're getting a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: look for extra characters before the json. Copy 100% of the response body of request from browser dev tools into a json validator

Comment: Also should be passing object not string to `var jqxhr = $.getJSON(lookupPath, jsonData)`

Comment: Please upvote and accept if my answer helped you with that problem, or comment on it if it didn't. Letting an answer sit for so long without any kind of feedback is not a very nice thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't encode any data yourself. jQuery will do that, you don't need to interfere.

Pass in the data as an object:

```
$(function () {
    $('#mydropdown').change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/" + location.pathname.split('/')[1] + "/lookup", {
            lookupIdentifier: "MY_LOOKUP",
            secondParam: "PARAM"
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log('AJAX Call Completed. Data: ', data);
        }).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log('Failed', jqXhr, textStatus, error);
        });
    });
});
```

Unrelated, but use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.